# Linear Contrasts and Anova in R

Tags: r, model, statistics, anova

I'm trying to understand this question (my teacher is on vacation) and I would appreciate some help.

> Using the “contr.sum” contrasts option, conduct a two-way analysis of variance (ANOVA) that includes Time and Area as main effects and an interaction between the two main effects.

I'm not really sure how to use contrasts to do ANOVA. My answers seem to be separate. I have created a model like so

```
modelCO1 = aov(CO~Time+Area+(Time*Area), data = WorkplaceCO)
```

But this has nothing to do with linear contrasts. Whenever I try to use this code

```
modelCO1$contrasts$Time
```

I get an output that just says

```
"contr.sum"
```

Which doesn't really tell me anything. Alternatively, I have done this

```
options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))

contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Area)
contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Time)
```

Which gave me an output of

```
> contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Area)
           [,1]
Nonsmoking    1
Smoking      -1
> contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Time)
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
7:00am     1    0    0    0    0
10:00am    0    1    0    0    0
11:00am    0    0    1    0    0
1:20pm     0    0    0    1    0
4:20pm     0    0    0    0    1
7:00pm    -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

But again, where does ANOVA fit in? Much obliged.

Comment: @DanNeely, I'm not sure "linear-algebra" is a relevant tag.  If there were a "linear-models" tag (maybe there should be); there's a "linearmodels" tagged but as described is Python-specific

Answer (score 2):

Setting contrasts needs to be done before you fit the model. So if you run `options(contrasts=c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))` before the call to `aov()` then you will get the model you want.  Note that the `options()` call changes the defaults for future calls to `contrasts()`; if you don't want that you can set contrasts on a factor without changing the defaults like this:

```
contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Area) <- contr.sum
contrasts(WorkplaceCO$Time) <- contr.sum
```

Whichever way you do it, it needs to be done before `aov()`.

Comment: Would the rest of the output be OK? I'm just not sure how my contrasts fit into my ANOVA since they don't seem  to link to each other.

Comment: The contrasts determine how the ANOVA coefficients get calculated. When you call `aov` with a factor that does not have `contrasts` already specified, it will get done automatically behind the scenes before the model is fitted (using the default contrast method). You can read more about this [here](http://talklab.psy.gla.ac.uk/tvw/catpred/) and [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm).